# Java: How to fix code duplication in multiple methods?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, design-patterns

I have some theoretical knowledge related to Design Patterns and now I have some issues to make these info and another ones in action.

I have the following 2 methods in my `ServiceImpl` class:

```
@Override
public MultipartFile exportA() throws IOException {
    
    // repeated lines-I same as exportB method (code omitted for brevity)
    
    // other lines special to exportA method

    // repeated lines-II same as exportB method (code omitted for brevity)
}
```

```
@Override
public MultipartFile exportB() throws IOException {
    
    // repeated lines-I same as exportA method (code omitted for brevity)
    
    // other lines special to exportB method

    // repeated lines-II same as exportA method (code omitted for brevity)
}
```

As it is shown, there are repeated parts in all of these methods. So, should I create 2 methods for repeated lines-I and II, eand then move these code blocks to these newly created 2 methods? Or, is there a better way for Design Patterns?

Comment: Well, one pattern that comes to mind here is ["Template method"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). However, just extracting `createWorkbook()` and `writeWorkbookToFile()`-methods might get you a good way in the right direction as a first step.

Comment: @Hulk Thanks for reply, I al so thought something like that. But what about the special  lines? Any example post using the code please?

Answer (score 0):

If I have well understood your statement, this sounds to me a
`Builder Pattern` that you are looking for. You methods are building a `MultipartFile` whereas the build process itself depends on 'arguments/parameters' (here I guess sheet file path) and distinct code (the one you referred to as "other lines special to this method").

For that I would create a class `MultipartFileBuilder` that does the staff and that I would call in each method; of course, by means of setting the appropriate parameters and "code" each time. The code is simply an implementation of the `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` functional interface used in the following code (*2) and other parameters are using simple setters as well (here (*1)).

Note that I invoked the `Consumer<T>` as lambda expression here (the c->... construct). And note also that the type parameter `<T>` in `Consumer<T>` here is a new class I introduced `MultipartFileBuildContext` to allow multiple information to be passed to the code you are willing to write in each method. I guest the 'sheet' var would be a starting point. You can add other information if you need to.

To summer up things, this is how the code would look :

```java
    
    @Override
    public MultipartFile exportMethodA() throws IOException {
        return new MultipartFileBuilder()
                .setSheetPath("sheetA/path") (*1)
                .setAction(c->{
                    //(*2) do your staff here for method A
                    // the "other lines special to this method"
                    XSSFSheet sheet=c.getSheet()
                    ...
                }).build();
    }

    @Override
    public MultipartFile exportMethodB() throws IOException {
        return new MultipartFileBuilder()
                .setSheetPath("sheetB/path") (*1)
                .setAction(c->{
                    //(*2) do your staff here for method B
                    // the "other lines special to this method"
                    XSSFSheet sheet=c.getSheet()
                    ...
                }).build();
    }

    class MultipartFileBuildContext {
        private XSSFSheet sheet;
        public MultipartFileBuildContext(XSSFSheet sheet){this.sheet=sheet;}
        public String getSheetPath() {
            return sheetPath;
        }
    }
    
    class MultipartFileBuilder {
        String sheetPath; 
        Consumer<MultipartFileBuildContext> action; 

        public String getSheetPath() {
            return sheetPath;
        }

        public MultipartFileBuilder setSheetPath(String sheetPath) {
            this.sheetPath = sheetPath;
            return this;
        }

        public Consumer<MultipartFileBuildContext> getAction() {
            return action;
        }

        public MultipartFileBuilder setAction(Consumer<MultipartFileBuildContext> action) {
            this.action = action;
            return this;
        }
        
        public MockMultipartFile build() {
            // repeated lines
            workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            sheet = workbook.createSheet(sheetPath);

            //
            if(action!=null){
                MultipartFileBuildContext c=new MultipartFileBuildContext(sheet);
                action.accept(c);
            }
        
        // repeated lines ======================================================
        outputFile = File.createTempFile(...);
        try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile)) {
                workbook.write(outputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LoggingUtils.error("Writing failed ", e);
            }
            final FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(outputFile);

            final String fileName = TextBundleUtil.read(...);
            return new MockMultipartFile(fileName,
                    fileName, CONTENT_TYPE, IOUtils.toByteArray(input));
            //
        }
    }
```

At the end, this pattern needs to be used with care because you need to factorize all that you can to make the builder really useful, but not too much to make it a "boat of anything". For instance, you can have as input the sheet path or an inputstream of it to make it more useful/generic.

Comment: What about Template Method?

Comment: As far as I understood, we extracted the independent parts and create a separate classes using these independent parts by using the approach above. Is that true?

Comment: In template method we will do more or less the same thing : we will create the template method that we called "builder" in this example and we will add abstract methods equivalent to the Consumer interface here), the drawback of the template method is that you must subclass the class whereas here you are creating a new instance of the builder.

Comment: One last thing, in Template Method you will add a new class as well, but as stated earlier, you will need to subclass it for each method to implement the hooks (the abstract methods). Il is ways cleaner with the example given, imho. And to reply your question : indeed you will extract the repeated code into a new class and make room for customization using "properties:getter/setter" for both data and processing.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am wondering could it be also good if I create a method for all the repeated code blocks and then call these methods from the repeated block line?

Comment: Of course you can. Like this one "genMethod(String sheetPath,        Consumer<MultipartFileBuildContext> action){...}" but, remember, encapsulation is driven by OOP not procedural. You can turn any OOP app to a procedural one, but should you?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding. I meant that, if it is also a proper way to extract `repeated lines-I` and `II` code blocks to 2 separate methods and call these methods from the repeated lines in  `exportA` and `exportB` methods? You gave me an example like ` Consumer<MultipartFileBuildContext>`, but I think I don't need to create anything related to Builder Pattern.

Comment: You mean "methodA(){callRepeated1();mySpecificCodeA..;callRepeated2();", in general? definitely yes!, but what if your code flow uses multiple parameters/branches to "build" on your logic, it rapidly becomes unmaintainable. methods/functions need to be both granular and reusable. So again, if you think that "callRepeated1();mySpecificCodeA..;callRepeated2();" defines a complex logic that is repeated (in what you called exportA and exportB), you should avoid and go with Builder Pattern. If not, and there is no complex logic behind it, just go with method calls as you suggested.